# Finding confidence interval for categorial data in python?

Tags: python

I have a column in my data by the name WHZ score (weight for height z score). They are classified into three groups:
-patients with whz score small than -3 (100 patients)

- patients with whz score between -3 and -2 (50 patients)
- patients with whz score between -2 and 2 (45 patients )
  How do I find confidence interval for this classified data?
  Note: I have a hard time dealing with this. I am new. Any help would be appreciated...
  Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.